# pasting url is not returning desired tab

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

The below application is updating the url based on row selected in the DT table and the selected tab. But what happens is, when the user copy paste the url in another tab, it is not opening the specific tab, instead it is opening the default page (url : http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/?tabs=tabs2)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- function(request) {
  shinyUI(navbarPage(
    "Title", id = "inTabset", selected = "Summary",
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                tabPanel(
                  "Readme",tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type="text/css", href="style.css"))
                ),
                tabPanel(
                  "Summary",
                  dataTableOutput("tab")))
  )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Make sure you only bookmark the tabsetPanel
  setBookmarkExclude(isolate(names(input)[names(input) != "tabs"]))
  
  # Every time the tab changes, store the app state as URL bookmark
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  
  # Set callback that stores the app state in the URL
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(paste0("?tabs=", input$tabs), mode = "replace")
  })
  # Set callback to restore the app state from the URL
  onRestore(function(state) {
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "tabs", selected = getQueryString()[["tabs"]])
  })
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris,selection = 'single')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tab_rows_selected, {
    insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(paste0("tabs",input$tab_rows_selected), "This a dynamically-added tab"),
              target = "Summary",select = TRUE
                
    )
  })
  

}


enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: No it won’t . The url is getting changed. But if you copy paste the url in another browser tab, it is always going to first page.

Comment: It goes to the second tab in my browser

Comment: Strange. Can you show me the video clip of that if you do not mind. Sorry I am unable to make the video is my laptop. So you are telling, you click on a row 2, a tab2 opens. Now if you copy this url and paste in on another tab, the same state is there (tab2 opens)? This is what you meant?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSRrP4-3BkZDIFdqRjPXGkoXnDPfQTid/view

Comment: I think you did not my point. please refer the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792535/bookmarking-reactive-tabs-not-working-in-shiny